# IonicFramework error installing Sass on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ionic-framework, sass

I use Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits and i'm trying to install Sass on Ionic with this command:

```
ionic setup sass
```

But, the result of this is:

```
npm WARN deprecated gulp-minify-css@0.3.13: Please use gulp-clean-css
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-56-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.12
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! path /home/thales/.npm/chalk/1.1.3
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/thales/.npm/chalk/1.1.3'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/thales/.npm/chalk/1.1.3']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/thales/.npm/chalk/1.1.3',
npm ERR!   parent: 'gulp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/thales/Desktop/mectria/npm-debug.log

Error running npm install



Exception with  (CLI v1.7.14)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.1.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 
Node Version: v0.12.12
```

I sought the solution but i didn't found nothing!
What should i do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According error log, It seems you have no write acces to directory */home/thales/.npm/* in your home, so maybe you can try to launch it as root or change access right in this folder.
Or you can try to set up sass manually without the Ionic cli helpers.

Comment: Thank You so much! It's Work